# JDBC driver not loading in Dataloader 37

Tags: configuration, database, oracle

I'm trying to configure Database as source in a Data Loader 37 bean, but at time to execute it from CLI I got an error message that specify the JDBC driver cannot be loaded, according to the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_dbaccess.htm the ojdbc.jar file should be in java\bin folder under the Data Loader installation but is not being recognized by the application. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I found this workaround https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k5rAAA/cannot-load-jdbc-driver-class-oraclejdbcdriveroracledriver-while-using-ojdbc-jar-with-dataloader but version 37 don't have the dataloader.bat file